# Salesforce Connected App : How to authentifiy with a single permanent api-key

Tags: authentication, salesforce

I have to expose a simple restResource to deal with API REST and specifically a POST request.
I developed an APEX class to do it, generating a platform event and a workflow on it.

I have to set up this URL endpoint in an external services where I can only hardcoded a single variable in the header (the name and the value)

How can I set up a connected app to expose only this RestResource and to authenticate with only a permanent token (api-key or other name) ?
Otherwise, do you know other method ?

I tried Oauth2 but discover the bearer token is not permanent.

Answer (score 0):

OAuth2 access_token (what you pass in `Authorization Bearer {token}`), also know as session id is not permanent, yes. But you control how long it's valid, up to 24 hours.

The effective value of the session timeout is:

- what's in the connected app's screen -> manage -> "timeout value"
- if empty - what's in connecting user's Profile -> session settings
- if empty - what's the org-wide default in Setup -> Session settings -> timeout value

(while you're at it might be good idea to set "password never expires" on the user's profile and reset the password 1 last time)

Furthermore using a token resets the countdown (just like when you click around in the browser the session still works). So you could design some "heartbeat" thing that pings your service every X hours just to keep the session open. There's "introspection" call if you don't want to call your code with stupid empty body: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.remoteaccess_oidc_token_introspection_endpoint.htm&type=5, just to check the session validity

It's not a great solution but would work... More appropriate would be to expose some "proxy", some integration like Mulesoft, BizTalk or something that can queue your messages and properly login to SF, maybe even bulk process them (because the API you created works 1 at a time, right? not great ;)) This would be better because credentials are easier to change (I mean... you should change passwords often, or use different authentication method like JWT) and if there's any fail - the queue of messages means stuff can resume after any issues. Error monitoring etc etc...

In a way Salesforce is wrong place to solve it, your technical architect should reconsider the solution.

---

If you can't schedule anything to keep the session alive, can't use a proper integration there is one more way but oh man is it insecure. You'll feel dirty afterwards.

1. Create a [Site](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.sites_overview.htm&language=en_US&type=5). Write down the URL. Let's say it will be `mycustomdomain.my.salesforce-sites.com/DirtyDirtyHack`
2. Edit the Site's [public access settings](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.sites_configuring_sites.htm&type=5) (also known as special hidden "{Site Name} Guest User" profile. Grant access to use your class.
3. Call your apex exposed over API as `mycustomdomain.my.salesforce-sites.com/DirtyDirtyHack/services/apexrest/incomingTextMessages` instead of `https://mycustomdomain.my.salesforce.com/services/apexrest/incomingTextMessages`. No authentication needed.
4. Your stuff will execute as that Guest User, there are some bandwith limitations but it works.
5. Put your own handmade "API key" as a header or URL parameter or something and then check that parameter in your Apex manually.
6. Take a long shower and try to forget this abomination.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Unfortunately, I have no choice but set up a public Site. Publising platform event is fine with the APEX class exposed but the platform-event trigger flow fails : "guest users are not permitted to perform this operation" (post to chatter or create a record). Is there a way to allow it or change the "run as" in flow ? Otherwise, I'll deal it in APEX class directly. Many thanks for your precious help (PS : I'm a social start up, so no architect or dedicated Salesforce / IT HR avaiable)

Comment: after searching, it appears Triggers work (automated process user) but triggered flows don't (contextual user = guest user). So I create a trigger that insert a task (first step of my workflow) that's trigger a record-triggered flow

Comment: You can make platform event handling (triggers) run as another user by deploying a special xml file https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_platformeventsubscriberconfig.htm. Don't think it works for flows though.
Publish as guest, handle as admin, carry on?